# Limit of vector and inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x$ be a vector such that $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Definition : $\bar{x}=\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{(n)}$ if and only if for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ $\| X-x^{(n)}\|<\epsilon$.

What I am trying to prove :

If $x^{(n)} \leq y^{(n)}$ and both sequences converge, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{(n)} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} y^{(n)}$.

What I tried:

I tried to prove it by contradiction. Suppose for contradiction that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{(n)} > \lim_{n\to \infty} y^{(n)}$.

Let $\epsilon =\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{(n)} - \lim_{n\to \infty} y^{(n)}=\bar{x}-\bar{y}>0$.

And somehow use $\epsilon$... but I am not sure from here.

I would really thank for your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying each component of $x^{(n)}$ is less than or equal to each component of $y^{(n)}$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not. Then writing $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, $y=(x_2,...,y_n)$, there exists $j$ such that $\overline{x}_j>\overline{y}_j$. Choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $\overline{x}_j-\epsilon>\overline{y}_j+\epsilon$. By definition of convergence, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N,$ we have $x_j^{(n)}>\overline{x}_j-\epsilon>\overline{y}_j+\epsilon>y_j^{(n)},$ a contradiction.